# corrected inline link syntax

Tags: support, links

Whenever I link a related/relevant question in a comment, I use the "share" static link of the question or answer I want to refer to. I've seen some comments where the link is replaced by the question title, but I'm not able to reproduce that behavior (without doing the `[link description](URL)` inline hyperlink).

Is this just not a feature on SE (because I distinctly remember reading somewhere that linked questions are automatically replaced by their titles) or is there some special magic need?

Comment: Comments where questions are linked by their title have normally been typeset using the normal `[title](url)` notation, unless I really missed a beat. If you're really curious about the plaintext of any given message, you can get it with a query of the form `select * from Comments where PostId = xxxxx` over at [data.se].

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thank you for the Data Explorer tip, I'll look into it if I find the comment I am thinking about. I also corrected the inline link syntax in the post `[title](url)` is for me the only way to make a link look nice in a comment, too.

Comment: You may be interested in [Use this userscript when you share a link](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7232/use-this-userscript-when-you-share-a-link) to automate the process, by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A question link is converted to its question title in questions & answers but not in comments. (In chat it is possible to one-box a question link.)

Comment: Ah, that is... remarkably anticlimactic (regarding the special magic I hoped for). Thank you!