# As a link in a comment how to mention the title of a question instead of its URL?

Tags: support, comments, links

In a comment, I want to write the title of a question (to point out that it's a duplicate or related stuff) instead of "pasting" its URL. How can I do that?

Comment: This is not an issue specific to Phys.SE. See the mother meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77394/209806 , https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85389/209806

Comment: Note also that adding an internal link in a comment causes the title of the target to appear in the "linked questions" sidebar.

Comment: Related: [Use this userscript when you share a link](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7232/use-this-userscript-when-you-share-a-link), which provides a quick and automated way to get the correct markdown to use in such a comment.

Answer (score 4):

I'm answering so that we can keep an easy copy here as a quick reference, but it's actually there in Qmechanic's comment.

Comments use a simplified version of markdown. To include links, use

```
[As a link in a comment how to mention the title of a question instead of its URL?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10699/as-a-link-in-a-comment-how-to-mention-the-title-of-a-question-instead-of-its-url)
```

The text which is expected to appear finally should be in square brackets, and the URL immediately follows that in normal brackets. You can't end the stuff inside the square brackets with a space, and you need to include the full URL: 'https://' and all. Note that this works in normal answers and questions as well.

Comment: I will add that it is possible to get the required format of the link more quickly if you use one of the useful bookmarklets collected here: [Bookmarklets for Stack Exchange](https://normalhuman.github.io/stackmarklets/). (Namely the *Formatted link to a webpage* bookmarklet. Of course, other stuff on that site might be useful, too.)